# Running a batch backup in Titanium stops my a set alarm on my alarm clock

Tags: titanium-backup

I recently switch from Helium backup to Titanium (still free version). I tried to use the scheduled backup and experienced a quite annoying effect: I ran the backup at 3am in the night - and my alarm scheduled for the moring was not working.

It seems that titanium stops apps for doing the backup (I think I read this somewhere), and my interpretation is that the alarm clock app cannot exec scheduled alarms once it has been stopped.

Is there a way I can exclude the alarm clock app? In fact, I really don't need a backup of my scheduled alarms ...

I run CyanogenMod 11 / Android 4.4.4

Comment: What's the issue with the clock? Yes, *TiBu* might need to stop apps to make a clean backup (`RESTART_PACKAGES`). I run scheduled backups every night, and have no issue with that. The Alarm Clock doesn't need to run continuously; for alarms, it gets "awoken" by the system (alarms are registered with the system). Btw: Running CM 11 here as well on multiple devices using different Alarm Clocks. And the full (paid) version of *TiBu*.

Comment: I just improved my question above; I experienced that the alarm clock was *not* working in the morning :-(

Comment: Can you also 1) add which alarm clock you are using, and b) try if the same happens with a different alarm clock? I have a nightly TiBu job running at 3am (as you do), alarms never failed me (firing around 6…7am). I use the "default clock" on one device, and *AlarmDroid* on another, both devices running CM 11/Android 4.4.4. Additionally: what kind of batch backup are you performing (e.g. all apps, changed only, …)? I could then compare with mine.

Comment: I used the CM 11 standard alarm clock app (however it is called). Good idea to try another one. It was the standard "backup changed data" job in Titanium without any modification.

Comment: OK, that's the same running here nightly. No such issues, neither with the standard alarm clock nor with *AlarmDroid*. I wonder what that should be, as "alarm clocks" usually register an alarm with the Android System, which then wakes them up at the set time so they can play their alarm. So as long as the alarm is not at the same time as the backup, that shouldn't matter at all. Sure you've set the alarm for that day, and it wasn't a one-timer already fired – or a repeating not including that day?

Comment: I have a Galaxy Nexus and I used nightly TB backups (free version) with the last Android update Google provided (4.3) and never experienced this, but recently I installed 7.1.1 AOSP from XDA and indeed, since I did, I can confirm that TB now stops the clock app and doesn't restart it. When the notification says that the clock app is being updated, the clock in the status bar indicating that an alarm is set, disappears, and doesn't come back until the clock app is restarted manually.

Comment: Can't edit comment after 5 mimnutes; OP is running 4.4.4, @Izzy is running CM1 which is 4.4 or 4.4.1 - maybe it's a bug in TB with newer Android versions ?

Comment: Good to hear s.o. else is also having this issue ;-) I didn't find a solution yet.

Comment: Just to clarify (I shouldn't write at night :-P) :
"s/7.1.1/7.1"
"s/updated/backed up"
"s/CM1/CM11"

Comment: Update : also happens under 7.1.1 on a brand new Nexus 5X.